# Inside MFSideMenuController viewwillappear method is not working

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7

I want to check a nsuserdefault value available or not, If value is available it should show Logout, if value is nill, It should show Login in the side menu I am doing that in viewwillappear method but it is not working, Please some one clarify on this.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *id1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"ID"];


    if (id1.length>0)
    {
        recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Account Details", **@"Logout",** @"Change Password", @"Contacts", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
    }

    else
    {
        recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Account Details", @"**Login**", @"Change Password", @"Contacts", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
    }


}
```

Comment: side menu 's viewWillAppear will be called only when you present MFSideMenuController and not every time you open the side view. You can put a breakpoint and debug to find the problem, are you getting empty string id1 or viewWillAppear is not called at all? 
It is difficult to figure out what the actual problem is with this much information

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that MFSidemenu is a pod used for drawer like functionality for showing menu.
The MFSidemenu has the following method to show the side menu.

```
[self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateLeftMenuOpen completion:^{}];
```

You can add your check for NSUserDefaults either before calling this method or in the completion block, whichever suits you.
The ViewWillAppear will not be called every time the side menu opens.

It also has a notification that you can observe to trigger when the SideMenu opens(i.e. menu will open, menu did open, etc.)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(menuStateEventOccurred:)
name:MFSideMenuStateNotificationEvent
object:nil];

- (void)menuStateEventOccurred:(NSNotification *)notification {
    MFSideMenuStateEvent event = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"eventType"] intValue];
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *containerViewController = notification.object;
// Check whether menu opens here and then add your code.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done that in thisway Now it is working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loginlogout:) name:@"login" object:nil];

}

- (void)loginlogout:(NSNotification *) notification
{


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *id1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"ID"];


    if (id1.length>0)
    {
        recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Account Details", @"Logout", @"Change Password", @"Contacts", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
    }

    else
    {
        recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Account Details", @"Login", @"Change Password", @"Contacts", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
    }
    [tableview1 reloadData];
}
```

Calling this loginlogout Method in otherpage (Any page you want to call)example 
Loginviewcontroller.M

```
- (IBAction)Logout:(id)sender

{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loginlogout:) name:@"login" object:nil];

}
```

Finally Delloc

```
- (void) dealloc
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"login" object:nil];
}
```